# Create new empty column and limit it to recieve certain data type and length of characters?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to create a new empty column and limit it to receive only numbers and `double` length.

In general how do I make a limitation when creating new columns? for example to receive only binary? or to limit it to 250 characters?

I have done these while creating databases with SQL but in pandas is new stuff.
I am thinking that after you create a column you can pass something like this:

```
df['col']='' # to create an empty column
df['col'] = df['col'].astype('str') #to make it string after being filled or not
```

but how to limit it to receive certain things like the ones mentioned above.

If you can answer these it will help a lot.

Comment: Pandas dataframe are not databases, therefore the lack some of the [ACID features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) that you'd normally find in RDBMS.  You'd have to achieve what you are asking for programmatically.